# How to use correctly error-message from Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I try to add a error message when i receive a error from axios.

I manage to put this message, but when i hit the v-text-field, the error message keep the error message, not update with rules message.

```
<v-text-field
        v-model="name"
        :counter="10"
        :rules="nameRules"
        :error-messages="nameErrorMessages"
        :error-count="nameErrorCount"
        label="Name"
        required
      ></v-text-field>
```

We find the same issue in this example : https://codepen.io/prasmi/pen/damNbm.

If somebody have a solution, I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the `v-text-field` [doc](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-text-field/#error-messages) say:

> `error-messages` Puts the input in an error state and passes through custom error messages. Will be combined with any validations that occur from the rules prop. This field will not trigger validation

This field will not trigger validation and you have to manage it on your own